# How to add a .class file folder to the classpath in eclim?

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath, eclim

How do I add a folder with .class files to the classpath to eclim?

I've tried the options in [the eclim official site](http://eclim.org/vim/java/classpath.html) but none of them works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is bonkers. You can use the UI that's *already provided by Eclipse for doing this*.

[image: The "J" project's Properties dialog]